# How can a script take different types of command line arguments and feed it to a java program?

Tags: java, bash, shell

So I need to make a java program that represents a bank tiller. However, I **need** to use an executable script that will feed the command line arguments to the java program. Unfortunately, there are multiple types of commands I can do that would need to call the java program.

Since there are different types of command options (start, buy, and change, I do not know how I could go about feeding the right argument information to the java program. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a `case` statement to execute different code depending on `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you could use `$@` to pass the script's arguments to your Java program. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export CLASSPATH="$HOME/src/java/"
java com.example.MyTeller "$@"
```

Comment: You should use `"$@"` to ensure that arguments are re-quoted.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I knew I could do that but I think I was overcomplicating it since there were multiple commands like start, buy, and change. However, I realized the java program will just sort that out.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the script arguments to your Java program:

```
java programName "$@"
```

Comment: Use them as arguments to the `java` command, and have your Java program read them from the command arguments.

Comment: I'd rather put the parameter checking/validation/parsing in the Java program instead, and have the shell script simply delegate all argument to the Java program

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
public class PrintArgs {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int x=0; x<args.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(arg[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
java PrintArgs start 80 = 10 2 2 2
```

The script I am not that sure about, but I you can look it up.  Google shell scripts arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache CLI stuff. Specifically the POSIX parser (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072482/command-line-parsing-with-apache-commons-cli.html)

It will enable you to specify POSIX style command line arguments (--buy {value} --sell {value})...

Comment: forgot to mention that you can do type checking etc